# What are the different approaches in developing a web-server?

Tags: http, tomcat, node.js, webserver

What are the different approaches in developing a web-server?
So I guess there are (1) multi-thread (2) event-loop, is there anything else? What would be the pros/cons of each approach? when would you use each? can you list specific impl' for each approache

Answer (score 4):

Different approach can be:

1. Single threaded: All connections are handled by a single thread that
   "listens" for and awaits for connections and processes requests.It
   is simple to implement but it is the most useless server as it can
   only serve request at a time
2. Multithreaded:The server listens for requests and each incoming
   request is allocated to a new thread to handle it.So each client
   connection is handled by its dedicated thread. This approach(unlike
   1) supports concurrent processing of client requests but does not
   scale well since each new request creates a new thread at the server
   and this takes a lot of resources.Eventually the server will hit a
   limit
3. Multithreaded-Pools:Same idea as (2) but instead of creating a new
   thread to handle each incoming request a thread from a thread-pool
   is used.I.e. threads are created and placed on a pool for later
   reuse.This scales very well supporting multiple client requests and
   it is the standard approach.E.g. Tomcat works like this.
4. Event-Queue:Each incoming request is placed into a queue and is
   processed by a background thread taking requests of the queue. It is
   non-blocking and this type of asynchronous processing also scales
   well.To be honest I am not sure if it is better than (3) in
   performance.I think that tomcat can be configured for this using the
   NIO architecture

Answer (score 0):

You should add non-blocking I/O.  Have a look at [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty).

Answer (score 0):

Some servers like G-WAN mix **Multithreaded-Pools** and **Event-Queues**, letting the server saturate CPU Cores with *each thread* processing many connections.

Disclamer: I am involved in the development of this project.